# How to assign blank value for Moment in angular?

Tags: angular-moment, moment-timezone

I want to store current date and time in database so i am using Moment in angular.

I want to assign blank value for DateTime that is of moment type.

As like InvoiceId is a number so 0 is assigned similarly that for string '' is assigned. How can I assign blank value for moment type?

Web Api Models:

```
public class Invoice

{
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Tax { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int GrandTotal { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SalesTransaction> SalesTransactions { get; set; }

}
```

Angular file:

```
   currentTime: any;

   invoiceData = {

   InvoiceId: 0,
   Tax: 0,
   GrandTotal: 0,
   DateTime: 

};
   this.invoiceData.DateTime = this.currentDateTime;


    this.serviceInvoice.createInvoice(this.invoiceData).subscribe(( dataInvoice ) => {
      console.log('Invoice -', dataInvoice);

    )};
```

Interface in angular:

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';

export interface InvoiceElement {

InvoiceId: number;
Tax: number;
GrandTotal: number;
DateTime: Moment;

}
```